# POSTMAN - "var jsonData = pm.response.json();" alone in Test is returning a TypeError

Tags: json, postman

**Edit** I somehow didn't include the fact that this is a postman question. This is specifically and issue i am running into in Postman.

When I make the call, I am returned a JSON

```
[
    {
        "StatusId": 889812,
        "Status": "ACCEPT TRIP",
        "Fields": [
            {
                "Id": "label",
                "DataType": "String",
                "Name": "If you can not make order appointments legally and safely, call OPS.",
                "Required": false,
                "DefaultValue": null,
                "Order": 0,
                "MaxLength": 100,
                "MinLength": 0
            },
            {
                "Id": "ordernumber",
                "DataType": "String",
                "Name": "ORDER NUMBER",
                "Required": true,
                "DefaultValue": null,
                "Order": 1,
                "MaxLength": 0,
                "MinLength": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When I get the response back the only thing in the Tests tab is

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
```

I get **TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

I am at a loss as to why, can someone explain? I tried using let instead of var but it made no difference.

Comment: What is `pm`?  What is this "Tests tab"?  What is the full error trace?  What *language* is this?

Comment: Do you have anything in the tests tab at the Collection or Folder level?

Comment: pm - POSTMAN : this is the object containing the script that is running, can access variables and has access to a read-only copy of the request or response.